# what is the cdn address of not minified version of backand.js

Tags: javascript, cdn, backand

In the [documnation](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/getting_started/sdk/index.html#getting-started) there is refference for

```
 <script src="//cdn.backand.net/backand/dist/1.8.11/backand.min.js"/>
```

but what is the address for not minified version. because `map` file for that version not work well and I would happy to debug the orginal file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 more in the cdn for this version. For map and debug use them

- http://cdn.backand.net/backand/dist/1.8.11/backand.min.js.map
- http://cdn.backand.net/backand/dist/1.8.11/backand.debug.js

Comment: found it while exploring backand cdn directory.

Comment: you provider her unique information and save a lot of time for a lot of people thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the source code on their github

https://github.com/backand/angular1-sdk

I believe the file you are looking for is this one:

https://github.com/backand/angular1-sdk/blob/master/dist/backand.provider.js

Comment: that nice. but github resouce can't use directly as a url for script tag. need to use some service like `https://cdnjs.com/` for make it usable . i recommended to update your answer with that